# What is the purpose of building multistage rockets, rather then packing more fuel into a single stage?

Tags: aerospace-engineering, rocketry

Reading an article about multistage rockets (not educated at all on the topic), and from the get go it seems to assume they are used/need to be used.

Comment: You may find rather a plethora of information on any site dedicated to rocketry or space exploration.  Also  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the rocket is propelled upwards, it expends fuel. So there is no need to carry half empty fuel tanks. By splitting it up into separate stages, you can simply drop off unneeded mass.

Comment: Searched specifically for this and it seems to be the case. Thanks.

Comment: ...especially that the mass that reaches the orbit is of order of 5% or less of the launch mass. It's pretty hard to make a rocket that would weigh less than 5% of the fuel it carries, never mind fitting any meaningful payload in that!

Comment: True, but short on details.  You should at least link to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation

Comment: Agree, this would get my +1 if it contained a short description of the rocket equation.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason is that each motor stage can be designed for different purposes to match the flights characteristics.

So, a relatively short high thrust burn to escape gravity

And a longer or continuous burn to accelerate over a course / trajectory

Can save weight and complexity so adjustable nozzles are not always needed.

Comment: Thrust to weight ratio does play a role, but I think another big factor would be the surrounding air pressure. Since a long nozzle at sea level would lead to an underexpanded exhaust and a short nozzle in vacuum would lead to an overexpanded exhaust, both of which would make the engine less efficient.

Comment: It is easy to see where Solar Mike's answer can directly apply to motor selection for a LV designer -- many chemical engines will either be categorized into [at least] the two bins of "atmospheric operation" or "vacuum operation"